# How do I use Graph API explorer or FQL to see all my wall posts from a particular person?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So here is the story, my girl wrote me on my wall and I got the notification but even 3 days later there is no sign of actually reading that wall post. I am obsessed about this because she wrote it from the hospital and it wont be soon that she writes again so I must read what she wrote. The notification has some ids associated with them to see if that helps. Please help me figure it out. Figured out using context id in this form but shows blank. Looks like the post still lives since deleted posts show a clear cut error. `https://www.facebook.com/ali.gajani/posts/content_id`

Edit: looks like the context id turned out to be my profile id. This is driving me crazy! I want to see that wall post at any cost and I am sure it's an Fb issue because the wall post has not been deleted!

Answer (score 2):

since you are not looking to make a whole application it is likely you can obtain the information you are looking for using the [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)  if you have the ID of the post, it could be relatively simple.  if not it could be more difficult.  The problem lies in why you can not see it on your wall.

If she changed the permissions on the post, or deleted it you will not be able to see it.  Even if she did not delete it, you will not be able to read it if it the applicable permissions are not there.  To be brief, if you cant see it now, you likely will not be able to programatically.

Good luck.

Comment: Check out my edit, last two lines, looks like I can.I have the post or as they call it context id. There are no permission issues so that point is out of question.

Comment: If it's not visible on facebook.com's interface it won't be visible in the API either

Comment: Thanks but why ? Looks like I need to do something as the answer below says. Show all last 5 posts from my girl friend on my wall

Answer (score 0):

Get the `read_stream` permission in the graph explorer, and you should be able to submit this fql query:

```
SELECT post_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = '<user id>'
```

This should show the stream stories that have showed up in your stream from the specified source (you could use page/group/user id there). Once you get the post_id, you could just copy-paste it to the graph api part, and see what facebook can tell about that object.

For the user id, you might need to look into the `/me/friends` relation with  the `[graph api]` part of the explorer.

Comment: No, it's the girl who wrote the post. However you could try make it more scoped with a `and target_id = me()` so it only show the stories that posted to you directly.

Comment: I saw the notification code and it shows my profile id as the context id. Any chance i can show all wall-posts or last 5 from that particular person?

Comment: The above query should do that, just insert that particular person's id in for the `source_id`. I'm not sure if the context id is the same, but you could try to use that as `where xid = 'your contex id'`. You could use `order by created_time desc` to make newer  ones show up first.

Comment: thanks the context id is the post id and since i do not have that i cant use the mentioned piece of query you stated.